# What is the fastest way to get scraped data from so many web pages?

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, web-scraping

I need to scrap about 40 random webpages at the same time.These pages vary on each request.
I have used rpcs in python to fetch the urls and scraped the data using BeautifulSoup. It takes about 25 seconds to scrap all the data and display on the screen.

To increase the speed i stored the data in appengine datastore so that each data is scraped only once and can be accessed from there quickly.

But the problem is-> as the size of the data increases in the datastore, it is taking too long to fetch the data from the datastore(more than the scraping).

Should i use memcache Or shift to mysql? Is mysql faster than gae-datastore?
Or is there any other better way to fetch the data as quickly as possible?

Comment: If the scraping process is "stopping", i.e. it waits for each request to finish before continuing, then that's a big room for improvements by using asynchronous design (forks) instead, so it'll process multiple webpages at once.

Comment: It is already asynchronous. I have used rpcs : [link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/asynchronousrequests).

Comment: Memcached will probably be fastest. However, if the time taken to retrieve data from the appengine datastore is badly degrading with the amount of rows you're storing then it sounds like there might be a problem with your query not effectively using indexes

Comment: @robert_b_clarke, Thanx.. It was a problem with my code.. it was fetching data for one or two urls again on every request..Now its working fine.. Should i still use Memcached?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I know about your app it would make sense to use memcache. It will be faster, and will automatically take care of things like expiring stale cache entries.